# Remote login using cURL - No cookies found

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I am trying to remote login using the following code:

```
$cookiefile = dirname(__FILE__)."/cookie.txt" ; 
$postData = array(
    '&email' => 'email',
    '&pwd' => 'password',
   // 'redirect_to' => 'http://example.com',
   // 'testing_cookie' => '1'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://exaple.com/login?cid=6',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
    CUROPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookiefile,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=> $cookiefile
));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
```

I am getting the error - No cookies found -

Sorry, but your browser doesn’t seem to accept cookies from our site. A cookie is a small data package stored in your browser that is needed for personal identification

Update:
Besides I am also getting error like:

`Notice: Use of undefined constant CUROPT_COOKIEJAR - assumed 'CUROPT_COOKIEJAR' in E:\wamp\www\remote-curl\curl_request.php`

Comment: `$cookiefile = dirname(__FILE__)."/cookie.txt" ;` - are you sure this file exists? (+ you are missing the dollar sign in your question).

Comment: dollar sign is there, but no I haven't created any file. I thought the file will be created on its own.

Comment: Right, however, you have a typo in `CUROPT_COOKIEJAR ` => `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR `

Comment: Thanks - that rid me of cookie error. but still I am getting the login screen. Nothing beyond that. - after the typo is corrected.